# can't addRange() to listview xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

```
public class TrackAdapter:BaseAdapter<TrackModel.Track>
    {
        LayoutInflater _inflater;
        List<TrackModel.Track> _tracks;

        public TrackAdapter(Context context)//, List<TrackModel.Track> tracks
        {
            _inflater=LayoutInflater.FromContext(context);
            //_tracks=tracks;
        }

        public void AddMoreList(List<TrackModel.Track> tracks)
        {
            _tracks.AddRange(tracks);
        }
        public void AddItems(List<TrackModel.Track>  tracks)
        {
            _tracks = tracks;
        }
```

I have tested on device but I got null exception at AddRange. If I replace AddMoreList into AddItems then app will run.

```
items = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TrackModel.RootObject> (result);
            TrackAdapter tAdapter = new TrackAdapter (this.Activity);
            tAdapter.AddMoreList (items.tracks);
            lst.Adapter = tAdapter;
            tAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged ();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an initial contributor to your adapter I would recommend to do it the following way:

```
public class TrackAdapter:BaseAdapter<TrackModel.Track>
{
    LayoutInflater _inflater;

    public List<TrackModel.Track> Tracks {get; set;}

    public TrackAdapter(Context context, List<TrackModel.Track> tracks)
    {
        _inflater = LayoutInflater.FromContext(context);
        Tracks = tracks;
    }

    ...
}
```

That way you initialize your adapter with a pre-filled list of tracks and expose that as a property you can operate on.

```
//Initial filled list
TrackAdapter tAdapter = new TrackAdapter (this.Activity, items.tracks);
...
//later in the code where you need to add or remove items
var adapter = lst.Adapter as TrackAdapter;

//add a single track
adapter.Tracks.Add(track);

//add multiple tracks
adapter.Tracks.AddRange(tracks);

//remove a single track
adapter.Tracks.Remove(track);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize _tracks first.

```
_tracks = new List<Track>();
```

Comment: but It will lost old data and add a new list data. I want to add more data